# Pythonで書いた外れ値のインデックスを求めるプログラムをMATLABで実現する方法

Tags: python, python3, matlab

以下のようにtxtファイルに書き出された７つのセンサのデータから
外れ値のインデックスを求めるプログラムを書きました。
このプログラムをMATLABで実行できるように書き換えたいのですが、
データ分析はPythonでしかやったことがなく

```
data = load ('data.txt');
```

でPythonコードのdata = np.array(data)辺りまでの処理ができたということは
見当がつくのですが、以降がわかりません。

txtファイル内のデータは以下とします。

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 12, 6, 6, 7]
```

実行プログラム

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

num_sensors = 7  # センサ数
thresh = 5  # 中央値との差がこの値より大きい場合は異常値と判断

data= pd.read_table("data.txt", header=None)
data = data.values.tolist()
#data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 12, 6, 6, 7])  
data = np.array(data)

data = data.reshape(-1, num_sensors)
outliner = np.abs(data - np.median(data, axis=0, keepdims =True)) >thresh
indices = np.where(outliner.ravel())
print(indices)

#出力
17
```

回答を受けての追記
Pythonの方のプログラムだと
**data = data.reshape(-1, num_sensors)**
の記述があるので、入力データが以下の場合

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 12, 6, 6, 7]
```

出力は
[5,17]

ですが、MATLABではどこで **data = data.reshape(-1, num_sensors)** の処理をやっているのかわかりません。

データがベクトルという前提条件もリストでしか保持していないので、説明いただけますと幸いです・

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data`は既にベクトルになっているとします。

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 12, 6, 6, 7];

num_sensors = 7;
thresh = 5;

data = reshape(data, [], num_sensors);

% 中央値
medianOfData = median(data);

% 中央値からの差を格納したベクトル
differences = abs(data - medianOfData);

% 差がthresh以上の要素のインデックス
outliers = find(differences > thresh);

% 18; インデックスは1から始まるので、Pythonより1大きい
disp(outliers)
```

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。
回答を受けて質問に追記させていただきました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @NPP 提示したコードを見ればわかると思うんですが、MABLABでいうベクトルは、一行または一列からなる行列のことです。Pythonでのリストに一番近いものです。MATLABでリストというと、別のものになります。MATLABを使うのなら、もう少しMATLABの基礎から勉強なさったらどうですか。

Comment: 勉強不足であることは申し訳ございませんが、取り急ぎ実装する必要があり勉強しながら動かしている次第です。MATLABのベクトルとPythonのリストが近いと考えて、MATLABでは、 data = data.reshape(-1, num_sensors) で各センサごとにまとめてから中央値を取る処理はしなくても、Pythonのコードとほとんど同じことが実装できるのはなぜでしょうか。

Comment: @NPP 逆にお聞きしたいのですが、リストをreshapeして行列にしてから、またあとで`outliner.ravel()`で1Dに戻しているのは何故ですか。非常に意図が分かりにくいです。

Comment: @NPP とりあえず、`reshape`を追加しました。

Comment: ７つのセンサのデータという明記が不明瞭であった点お詫びします。dataは、単純な時系列データではなく、[センサno,1, センサno,2, センサno,3, ...センサno,7, センサno,1,...]という風になっていて、要素+7番目の値同士が関係しており、  要素+7番目の値同士の外れ値を探しているです。

Comment: ご回答を採用させていただきたいのですが、リストをreshapeして行列にしてから、またあとでoutliner.ravel()で1Dに戻す操作について、意図は正しく伝わりましたでしょうか。ご一報いただけますと幸いです。